# Odd Behaviour in SOQL Query

Tags: apex, soql

I have some odd behaviour with a SOQL query in an Apex class.

```
Set<String> contentDocumentIds = new Set<String>();
Set<String> contentVersionIds = new Set<String>();

contentDocumentIds.add('0694L00000575o8QAA');
contentDocumentIds.add('0694L0000057iUjQAI');

ContentVersion[] cvs = [SELECT Id, IsLatest 
                       From    ContentVersion 
                       WHERE   (ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds AND IsLatest = true)
                       OR      (Id IN :contentVersionIds)];
system.debug(cvs);

ContentVersion[] cvs2 = [SELECT Id, IsLatest 
                         From   ContentVersion 
                         WHERE  ContentDocumentId IN :contentDocumentIds AND IsLatest = true];
system.debug(cvs2);
```

The two ContentDocumentIds are valid and have ContentVersions with IsLatest=True. The first query returns one row, the second query (with the OR clause removed) returns two rows. Here's the output: -

```
> [11]|DEBUG|(ContentVersion:{Id=0684L0000057TM9QAM, IsLatest=true})
> [16]|DEBUG|(ContentVersion:{Id=0684L00000587HUQAY, IsLatest=true},
> ContentVersion:{Id=0684L0000057TM9QAM, IsLatest=true})
```

This feels like a problem with the SF query parser. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Please add isLatest to your SELECT statement and rerun.  Please update your debug log.  I think you will find that your assumptions are incorrect.  If they are both IsLatest = true, we are going to need more information to solve.

Comment: A general comment, this looks like you are looking for zebras in a herd of horses... we all do it... 99.9999% of the time the answer isn't that Salesforce is broke, it is that you have made a bad assumption...   When I find myself saying, well Salesforce is broke, I step away from the keyboard, take a short walk (increasing the oxygen to the brain) and look at it again.

Comment: more truthful would be to say that I swear at salesforce for a bit, telling myself that it can't be my issue, waste an undetermined amount of time, and *then* step away from the keyboard....

Comment: You added a filter where `Id IN :emptyCollection`, causing a table scan. You should look at your query plan and possibly **[edit]** your question to include the size of the table and the selectivity changes in the queries.

Comment: @dbwood3 
[11]|DEBUG|(ContentVersion:{Id=0684L0000057TM9QAM, IsLatest=true})
[16]|DEBUG|(ContentVersion:{Id=0684L00000587HUQAY, IsLatest=true}, ContentVersion:{Id=0684L0000057TM9QAM, IsLatest=true})

Comment: Wow.  I'm speechless... but I will put a bounty up to see if we can get an answer.

Comment: Do you have lots of ContentDocuments in your org? I presume Adrian is correct in that the empty set/table scan is causing you issues as there's probably a limit being applied so the "other" record isn't returned in the truncated returned values. There's a perm that can be turned on by support to remove this limitation that I ran into when dealing with a query against ContentDocumentLink in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335594/contentdocumentlink-query-returns-different-results-based-on-linkedentityid-size) that I suspect is related to this.

Answer (score 10):

This behavior is related to how `ContentVersion`, `Document` and `ContentDocumentLink` interact with each other and how they are accessed. Your first query is "open" (`OR`), your second query is "closed".

Therefore, the first query should only return "accessible" content versions, the second query should include everything that is explicitly filtered.

## TL;DR

Here are little bit more details, how `SOQL` behaves when querying content versions:

1. In Apex, Content Versions are only visible to the user that created them or that has **explicit** sharing access. This is not affected by "View All Data" and `without sharing`
2. You can still retrieve content versions if you know their Ids directly (Even though you could not access them in a regular query).
3. You always need a proxy (such as a parent record, where the content version is shared), to reliably retrieve content versions.

## Accessibility of Content Versions

If you query for content versions, a user only sees **his/her content versions**. That includes versions where the user is the owner of the version, or he/she has explicit sharing access (through manual sharing) to the specific document.

It appears to be completely non deterministic, because the user may be able to access the content version via the UI.

There is a permission that can be enabled, that circumvents this. However, this permission requires view all data and setup, so that's nothing you should use for your regular users (and as a result, it can't fix issues that appear in production code that runs in user scope).

[image: View all data permission for content versions]

To verify, that you are affected by this behavior (and not something even odder), kindly check if the executing user is owner of both documents you try to retrieve. If not, play around with explicit sharing and try to reproduce this behavior.

## How to query for content versions reliably

A content version is always accessible by it's Id, even though you could not access it in an "open" query.

```sql
SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion
```

So as you already found out, this query only retrieves the content versions that you have explicit access to.

To make things harder for us, you cannot use `ContentDocumentLink` in a sub-query. You need to write apex code to extract the relevant `ContentVersionId`, build a list of ids and query for these Ids particularly. And this is where it get's interesting: **You require a proxy** like the `LinkedEntity` to find content versions and their documents. You cannot simply access them directly, without knowing the places where they are shared.

```
SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN :contentVersionIds
```

This query will retrieve all content versions, in the list of Ids. This will include content versions, that are not present in the first query.

This get's extremely annoying, if you have to identify a `Document` based on a content version. If you do not own the version, the full document will be *invisible* to your query.

Here is code that I wrote to retrieve all the content versions of a service contract. It takes the list of
and return the parent content document. You could easily use this to retrieve all content versions.

```java
public static Map<Id, ContentDocument> getLatestContractSummaryDocuments(List<Id> serviceContractIds) {
    Map<Id, ServiceContract> crs = new Map<Id, ServiceContract>(
        [
            SELECT
                Id,
                (
                    SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId, ContentDocument.Title, LinkedEntityId
                    FROM ContentDocumentLinks
                    ORDER BY Id ASC
                )
            FROM ServiceContract
            WHERE Id IN :serviceContractIds
        ]
    );
    List<Id> contentVersionIds = new List<Id>();
    for (ServiceContract sc : crs.values()) {
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : sc.ContentDocumentLinks) {
            contentVersionIds.add(cdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, ContentVersion> contentVersions = new Map<Id, ContentVersion>(
        [
            SELECT Id, Title, DocumentTemplateName__c, ContentDocumentId
            FROM ContentVersion
            WHERE Id IN :contentVersionIds AND DocumentTemplateName__c = 'CONTRACT_SUMMARY'
        ]
    );
    Map<Id, ContentDocument> documentsByContractIds = new Map<Id, ContentDocument>();
    for (Id contractId : serviceContractIds) {
        documentsByContractIds.put(contractId, null);
        ServiceContract sc = crs.get(contractId);
        if (sc == null) {
            continue;
        }
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : sc.ContentDocumentLinks) {
            if (contentVersions.containsKey(cdl.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId)) {
                documentsByContractIds.put(contractId, cdl.ContentDocument);
            }
        }
    }
    return documentsByContractIds;
}
```

In the particular use case I am only interested in content versions of a specific type, that's the filter on the `DocumentTemplateName__c`